# Philosophy and Mindset

Tags: philosophy-of-science

`All humans can think, question and make decisions. Because of that, all humans are philosophers according to their mindset.`

Does any philosopher argue like that? Is this True of False?

Comment: I made an edit. You may roll this back or continue editing. To help provide more context were you reading something that stimulated this question? This might help with someone providing an answer.

Comment: But then almost any complex enough form is a philosopher: an ant, a rat, a worm. But philosophers' questions are qualitively different.

Comment: It seems to me this is a question of the definition of "philosopher", and I can't say it's a very useful one.  (BTW, it isn't clear that all humans can think, question, and make decisions.  I've known some who showed no sign of being able to do all three at certain times in their lives.)

Comment: This reminds me a parody of some commercials. "Do you go to sleep at night and wake up in the morning? If so, you need our product."

Answer (score 1):

There is *some* truth to this that I think is important to acknowledge: to be a philosopher one does not necessarily have a PhD in philosophy, or have 'philosopher' as a job title. To be a philosopher is indeed more about a certain mindset that involves the things you mention.  I think this is important, because some people may scoff at philosophy and think it's a waste of time; that philosophy (boo!) is fundamentally distinct from science (yay!). But in both philosophy and science we think carefully about things .. and of course *everyone* does this at some point or other. So, philosophy shouldn't be as 'weird' or 'alien' or 'useless' as people make it out to be. I think it's good for people to realize this.

That said, in practice, we do make distinctions, and doing philosophy, as we use the word in real life, seems to involve a good bit more than questioning and careful thinking; it needs to be about certain subjects, for example. And, there is a certain rhetorical 'style' to doing philosophy; scientists wear lab coats, philosophers sit in arm chairs, etc. So, from the perspective for how we use the word in practice to demarcate the world around us, thinking, questioning, and decision making is not sufficient to be a philosopher. Indeed, it wouldn't be a very useful word if everyone was a philosopher.

Answer (score 0):

> All humans can think, question and make decisions. Because of that, all humans are philosophers according to their mindset.

**I think the quoted  statement is  not true.**

If one looks at 'philosophy' and analyzes its nature then those thinking men who profess the process can be associated with the term 'philosopher'.

> Philosophy is not a "Way of Life". Every person does not have his or her own "Philosophy".   It is not simply a theory about something.
>   Nor is Philosophy a belief or a wish.
>   It is an activity: a quest after wisdom.
>   Philosophy is an activity of thought. a particularly unique type of thought or style of thinking
>   What a philosopher provides is a body of philosophic thought NOT a Philosophy.
>   A philosopher enacts a Philosophy, a quest after wisdom.

Philosophy is not a picking and choosing what body of thought one would like to call one's own or would like to believe in; a choice based upon personal preferences or feelings.  Philosophy is a pursuit.  One can choose to be philosophical.

> One can choose or may not choose to be a philosopher.  Philosophy, insofar as it may be correlated at all to a "way of Life", is a form of thinking meant to guide action or to prescribe a way of life.

The philosophic way of life, if there is one, is displayed in a life in which action is held to be best directed when philosophical reflection has provided that direction; e.g., SOCRATES the paradigm of a philosopher.

Philosophy is an activity of thought, a type of thinking.
Philosophy is critical and comprehensive thought, the most critical and comprehensive manner of thinking which the human species has yet devised.

> This intellectual process includes both an analytic and synthetic mode of operation.  Philosophy as a critical and comprehensive process of thought involves resolving confusion, unmasking assumptions, revealing presuppositions, distinguishing importance, testing positions, correcting distortions, looking for reasons, examining world-views and questioning conceptual frameworks.
>
> It also includes dispelling ignorance, enriching understanding, broadening experience, expanding horizons, developing imagination, controlling emotion, exploring values, fixing beliefs by rational inquiry, establishing habits of acting, widening considerations, synthesizing knowledge and questing for wisdom.
>
> Philosophy as a process functions as an activity which responds to society's demand for wisdom, which is bringing together all that we know in order to obtain what we value.  Viewed in this way Philosophy is part of the activity of human growth and thus an integral, essential part of the process of education.  Philosophy and education have as a common goal the development of the total intellect of a person, the realization of the human potential.

What type of thought is Philosophy?

one can go on and on...
therefore the statement below seems not to be 'true'.

Ref.- >http://www.qcc.cuny.edu/SocialSciences/ppecorino/INTRO_TEXT/Chapter%2012Conclusion/What_is_Philosophy.htm